# Couldn't find folder location (java.lang.IllegalStateException)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty

```
    public class AppServer {
    public static final String WEB_INF_LOCATION = "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml";
    public static final String WEB_APP_LOCATION = "../ui/app";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = Integer.valueOf(Optional.fromNullable(System.getenv("PORT")).or("8080"));
        WebServer server = new JettyWebServer(WEB_INF_LOCATION, WEB_APP_LOCATION, port, "0.0.0.0");


        System.setProperty("restx.mode", System.getProperty("restx.mode", "dev"));
        System.setProperty("restx.app.package", "orange.invoice");

        server.startAndAwait();
    }
}
```

**Error:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't find ../ui/app in /Users/Kevin/Development/orange
Check your working directory.

```
at restx.common.MoreFiles.checkFileExists(MoreFiles.java:103)
at restx.server.JettyWebServer.<init>(JettyWebServer.java:44)
at orange.invoice.AppServer.main(AppServer.java:20)
```

I have the code definition above and I am getting the error despite the fact that the '..ui/app' location is correct. Can anyone help please?

Comment: i have tried things like deleting the .idea folder etc but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `WEB_APP_LOCATION` is sourced from the project directory, so it is looking for `/Users/Kevin/Development/ui/app`.  Maybe you need to set it to `src/main/webapp/ui/app`?

Update:
You can set the value to just `ui/app`.  By adding the `../`, you were moving up to the parent of the project directory.

Comment: @UniversalCodeLabs what is the folder structure?  Can you add the locations to the original question?

Answer (score -1):

It finally worked like this:

```
public static final String WEB_INF_LOCATION = "/Users/Kevin/Development/orange/server/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml";
public static final String WEB_APP_LOCATION = "/Users/Kevin/Development/orange/ui/app";
```

- orange is project folder name

Comment: Only true on your machine.  Better to not have to rely on a path this way.